# What format is this data in?

Tags: php, arrays

What format is this in? Using a CMS that spits out this under `var_dump($_SESSION['userinfo'])`. I need to be able to get the 'pilotid' from this information in PHP, which in this case is 6.

```
string(728) "O:8:"stdClass":23:{s:7:"pilotid";s:1:"6";s:9:"firstname";s:5:"James";s:8:"lastname";s:7:"Allison";s:5:"email";s:25:"jamesallison.uk@gmail.com";s:4:"code";s:3:"BAW";s:8:"location";s:2:"GB";s:3:"hub";s:4:"EGKK";s:8:"password";s:32:"4c34d29d886cf388938b5b574a73b938";s:4:"salt";s:32:"19cb40ac74bbc04d296b055f7c2f26e1";s:7:"bgimage";s:14:"background.png";s:9:"lastlogin";s:10:"2013-11-25";s:12:"totalflights";s:1:"0";s:10:"totalhours";s:1:"0";s:8:"totalpay";s:1:"0";s:13:"transferhours";s:1:"0";s:6:"rankid";s:1:"1";s:4:"rank";s:8:"New Hire";s:9:"ranklevel";s:1:"1";s:9:"confirmed";s:1:"1";s:7:"retired";s:1:"0";s:8:"joindate";s:19:"2013-11-24 17:28:33";s:9:"lastpirep";s:19:"0000-00-00 00:00:00";s:6:"lastip";s:13:"81.157.87.138";}"
```

Thanks

Comment: try `var_dump(unserialize($_SESSION['userinfo']));` I suppose you will be able to access `$obj = unserialize($_SESSION['userinfo']); echo $obj->pilotid;`

Comment: It's a serialisation of a `stdClass` object, which is a predefined class in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing `serialized` data see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 1):

The string is formatted by the serialize function.

You can read more about [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

You have to unserialize the string, so it will get back to its original object.

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['userinfo'], true)) . '</pre>';
```